# Como pegar um valor específico de um objeto?

Tags: php, objetos

Recebo esse objeto em PHP (consegui ver os valores com print_r):

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 ) 1
```

Queria dar um echo apenas no valor do id (1), como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está recebendo um objeto, você deve acessar de maneira semelhante a um array. O que muda é que ao invés de `$variavel['id']`, você utiliza `$variavel->id`;

No seu caso, você obtêm o resultado assim:

```
echo $objeto->id;
```